# Reference class property in for loop

Tags: python

I'm new to classes in python and am looking for someone to explain why I'm running into this issue.

I have this class:

```
class TrackingMeasure:
    Touches = 'Possessions'
    DefensiveImpact = 'Defense'
```

When I attempt to run this loop:

```
tracking_refs = ['Touches','DefensiveImpact']
for x in tracking_refs:
    print(TrackingMeasure.x)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'TrackingMeasure' has no attribute 'x'
```

I'm sure this will be very easy for someone to explain so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It would likely be much better to have an internal dictionary, and just do a lookup of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the internal dict of the class to do that:

```
print(TrackingMeasure.__dict__[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr`:

```
tracking_refs = ['Touches','DefensiveImpact']
for x in tracking_refs:
    print(getattr(TrackingMeasure, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

getattr(object,string)

```
this_tm = TrackingMeasure
for x in tracking_refs:
    print(getattr(this_tm,x))
```

Comment: What is `this_tm` for?

Comment: fair question. I see that my solution creates an instance of the object and your solution references the class

Comment: If you intended to create an instance, you're missing the parentheses.